# Is it possible to combine a table and Gantt chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have created a Gantt chart in Plotly Express

```
fig = px.timeline(short_term, x_start="Starting Date2", x_end="Ending Date2", y="Concat",color="Input Quantity", text="Input Quantity",title = "Production Plan")
fig.add_vline(x=date, line_width=3, line_color="black")
fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") # otherwise tasks are listed from the bottom up
fig.show()
```

The y = "Concat" is actually a string where I have concatenated some of the information I need for each line in the Gantt chart. But this is not a very elegant solution. Is there any way to put a table or similar right to the left of the chart with the information, or include it in the chart some how? I have an illustration of how it looks now:
[image]

Comment: The right way would be to add the y-text you want seen as a column in the dataframe `short_term` so that plotly will take care of the plotting. What is the content of `Concat`, string or an array? Can you not add the relevant text as a column?

Comment: @Redox - if I add it as a column then it does not look all that pretty, because I need the following informatio: "Order number", "Item number", "Item description", "Quantity". If I add that just as a concatenated string with some kind of seperator between it will look messy as item numbers can vary between 2-15 characters. And I also cannot make any header that would match a normal column structure?